# How can I make screenshot of the part of the screen with ImageMagick?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, screenshot

I use Windows 8. I have coordinates of the part of the screen and I want to make screenshot only of that rectangle. How can I do it with ImageMagick?

Comment: What OS/platform are you on?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=24702

Comment: @MarkSetchell I need to make screenshot of the part of the screen, not of the active window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have at least ImageMagick 6.8.9-0 you can do the following to take a screenshot of part of your screen:

```
convert screenshot: -crop 100x100+500+500 screenshot.png
```

In example above,  `-crop` operation cuts out a rectangle that is 100x100 (`width` and `height`) at position 500x500 (`x` and `y` of the top left corner of the rectangle). And if your computer has multiple monitors you can specify an index `screenshot:[1]`. The index of the monitor starts with `0`, so first monitor will have index `0`.

```
convert screenshot:[1] -crop 100x100+500+500 screenshot.png
```